# How can two azure websites have their slots swapped at the same time?

Tags: deployment, azure-web-app-service

Two azure websites - one front-end, the other server API. They depend on each other. How can I swap both websites from staging slot to production slot simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

- You have a front-end with 2 slots: production and staging.
- You have 2 server sites.
- Each front-end slot points to a different server.
- You update the "non-active" server.
- Then update the staging front-end (pointing to that "non-active" server).
- Then swap the front-ends.

The new production front-end should still point to the same server which now becomes "active".

Comment: Yeah that makes sense

Comment: Clarification, by two server sites you mean two sites not additional deployment slots since _scaling is not available for non-production slots_. While deployment slots are sites of their own, they do have limitations.